# The $_POST['verandernaam'] stays blanco

Tags: php, html, css

```
if($_POST['submit2']) { // check of de button is geklikt
    $opdracht = $_POST['opdrachten'];
    $opdrachtgegevens = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `opdracht` WHERE `opdrachtnaam` = '$opdracht' ");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($opdrachtgegevens)) {
      ?>
        <?php
$rijopdrachtID = $row['opdrachtID'];
?>


        <br>
        <br>
    <div id="container">

        <div class="vlak" id="opdr_naam"><p>Opdrachtnaam : <?php echo $row['opdrachtnaam']; ?> </p>

            <?php

            $verandernaam=$_POST['verandernaam'];
            $vernaam = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE opdracht SET opdrachtnaam = '$verandernaam' WHERE opdrachtID = '$rijopdrachtID' ");


            ?>

            <form action="#" method="POST" >
                <label>Verander naam van opdracht:</label><br>

                <input type="text" name="verandernaam">

                <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="uploaden">
                </form>
        </div>
```

Why does the post variable stay "blanco"?
what do I do wrong, is it because it is in a while loop?

Comment: Which part is within the while loop? Can you please specify the while loop?

Comment: I've corrected your language a bit as well as the code markup. You might still want to edit it to make your question more clear. It would help to bringt it down to a clear, minimal example. At the moment, there is much disturbing clutter in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the best if you place your update query on the top of your page.

Try this:

```
<?php

   if (isset($_POST['submit3'])) {

       $verandernaam  =  $_POST['verandernaam'];

       $vernaam = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE opdracht SET opdrachtnaam = '".$verandernaam."' WHERE opdrachtID = '".$rijopdrachtID."' ");
   }

 ?>

/* Other code */

/* Write your while loop code here */
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand what you mean. but i'm getting the variable $rijopdrachtID out of the whileloop

Comment: I see. Can you post your entire code, please? Including the while loop?

Comment: can i send it to your mailbox?

Comment: Yes, please. Go head.